# Nestjs HttpService error handling with AxiosRequestConfig's validateStatus function

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, httpmodule, httpservice

I need to handle http errors status code (such as 401, 500, etc) which can occur when consuming an external service using HttpService (HttpModule of Nestjs). Here is the implementation i am working on:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import { catchError, firstValueFrom, map } from 'rxjs';

type Person = {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  async findPerson(): Promise<Person> {
    const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://service.dns/path/person',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
      validateStatus: function (status: number) {
        return status === 200;
      },
    };

    const personInstance: Person = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.request(axiosConfig).pipe(
        catchError((e) => {
          Logger.error(e.response.data.errorMessage);
          throw new Error('internal communication error');
        }),
        map((res) => {
          return res.data;
        }),
      ),
    );
    return personInstance;
  }
}
```

In the code above, I just need the function `catchError` throws the custom error, but I am not able to make the function `validateStatus` to trigger the execution of `catchError`.

Comment: this answer may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601651/how-to-rethrow-errors-of-httpservice-call-with-nestjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented next code in order to take advantage of `validateStatus` function of `AxiosRequestConfig` for giving solution to my needs:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

type Person = {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
  async findPerson(): Promise<Person> {
    const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://service.dns/path/person',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer fake_jwt`,
      },
      validateStatus: function (status: number) {
        return status === 200;
      },
    };

    return firstValueFrom(this.httpService.request(axiosConfig))
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((e) => {
        Logger.error(e.errorMessage);
        throw new Error('internal communication error');
      });
  }
}
```

**Note:** this code deals with `Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>` instead of `Observable<AxiosResponse<any>` methods